# Calculation the Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I want to calculate the standard deviation of the following numbers:
`30, 45, 45, 60, 75, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120`.
As far as I know, that would be

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{10}((30-75.5)^2+(45-75.5)^2+(45-75.5)^2+(60-75.5)^2+(75-75.5)^2+(80-75.5)^2+(90-75.5)^2+(100-75.5)^2+(110-75.5)^2+(120-75.5)^2)}$ = 28.587585

This site: http://de.numberempire.com/statisticscalculator.php got it right, but according to my book and this site: http://rechneronline.de/durchschnitt/ the result it `30.134`.

So what's the right result and how come it differs?

Comment: There are different types of standard deviation, namely the sample and population.

Comment: They are probably asking for the unbiased estimate. $s_{n-1}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}s_{n}$ where $s_{n-1}$ is the unbiased estimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there are two different types of standard deviation. You are calculating the bias estimate. Your book most probably wants the unbiased estimate. $s_{n-1}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}s_{n}$ Use n=10 for the number of values. You can see where the difference comes from

Comment: Thank you. When an exercise says, I should calculate the standard deviation, which one should I go for? I there a "standard" standard deviation?

Comment: You should go for the unbiased estimate. If you were to calculate it on the calculator there is a special symbol for it so make sure to check it out.